# Dropdownlist from database in MVC5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html.dropdownlistfor

**ViewModel:**

```
public class GroepModel
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public String Naam { get; set; }
        public String Beschrijving { get; set; }
    }
```

**Controller:**

```
public class GroepController : Controller
{
    AlinaDatabaseDataContext db = new AlinaDatabaseDataContext();
    // GET: Groep
    public ActionResult Groepen()
    {
        List<GroepModel> groepen = Mapper.Map<List<GroepenWerkvorm>, List<GroepModel>>(db.GroepenWerkvorms.ToList());

        return View(groepen);
    }
}
```

**View**

```
@model alina1617.Models.GroepModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Groepen";
}

<h2>Groepen</h2>
<div>
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model. //This is not working  )
</div>
```

I've looked around and a lot of the things I'm finding solve this using ViewBags, but isn't it suboptimal to use them? So what would be the best approach to get a dropdownlist using a model class with data from a database?

Comment: First off, your view uses a property called `Name`, but in your `GroepModel` you do not have a property called `Name`

Comment: Doesn't generate anything when I type model. (so no properties are even showing), hence why I accidently typed name, it's not working at all though. Basically it says 'no overload for DropDownListFor takes 0 arguments.

Comment: Can it be from your DatabaseContext class? how is it connected?

Comment: use @model  IEnumerable<alina1617.Models.GroepModel> when returning the list items and retrieve the items using @foreach(var item in Model)

Comment: your dropdown requires `IEnemurable<SelectListItem>` type.. But you are providing your custom type..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

first you need to add an SelectList to your viewModel :

```
public class MyViewModel {
   public SelectList list {get;set;}
   public int selectedItem {get;set;}
}
```

then you need to add your list to the SelectList :

```
public class GroepController : Controller
{
    AlinaDatabaseDataContext db = new AlinaDatabaseDataContext();
    // GET: Groep
    public ActionResult Groepen()
    {
        List<GroepModel> groepen = Mapper.Map<List<GroepenWerkvorm>,     List<GroepModel>>(db.GroepenWerkvorms.ToList());

        var model = new MyViewModel();

        model.list = new SelectList(groepen, "id", "Naam");

        return View(model);
    }
}
```

and in the view :

```
@model alina1617.Models.MyViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Groepen";
}

<h2>Groepen</h2>
<div>
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.selectedItem, Model.list  )
</div>
```

Comment: Quick question, what if I DO put it in a viewbag (because I need multiple dropdownlists on a single view). I tried:

@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.selectedItem, ViewBag.model.list,"Selecteer een groep") but that doesn't seem to work, nor does @Html.DropDownListFor( ViewBag.model.list,"Selecteer een groep")

Comment: Found it:  @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.selectedItem, ViewBag.model.list as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>,"Selecteer een groep")